# Accessing Port Forwarded address in android

Tags: php, android, portforwarding

When I connect to the localhost or my internal IP from the android emulator my app connects to the database. Also when the external IP is port forwarded and friends from other network can access the files using the same address on their browser.
I have added the code in `string.xml` as

```
 <string name="ip_addr">49.186.*.*:8510</string>
```

and on java files I have:

```
String ip = getResources().getString(R.string.ip_addr);
String url_get_comm = "http://" + ip+ "/getUsers.php";
```

when I asked them to download the app,they are unable to access the data with external IP but they can access the page on the browser. Can anyone help me where I am going wrong.

Comment: 'When i assign my internal ip to the string name it works well '. What do you consider to be 'the internal ip of your emulator'? Please just write down the ip's you use. Still using an emulator? No device? You realise that every pc or phone or emulator is it's own 'local host'? So if you are talking about local host then first tell of which device.

Comment: Why do you have `*.*`in the XML? Surly you need to enter the full IP?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson: yes, its the external IP, while posting it here i marked it off as *.*

Comment: @greenapps: I am a hardcore supporter of WP so no android phone ;) . 
Internal IP:  192.168.*.*  and external IP : 49.186.*.*

Comment: Aha, got it. Had to ask. :) (Btw.. WP rocks)

Comment: Yep it really rocks !!! 
I checked the php file and found I was statically connecting to 127.0.0.1 . Probably solved my problem. I will ask one to check it.

Comment: But the PHP-file and the database is on the same server? Then 127.0.0.1 should work regardless where the call comes from.

Comment: yes the are on the same server. Thats what I was thinking, on the db_config.php file i have added define('DB_SERVER', "192.168.2.101:3306");
on which one from other network can connect.